# CSS Flexbox horizontal groups; all left except one right

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>
<div class="set">
<div class="set">
<div class="set">
<div class="set">
<div class="set">
<span>123</span>
</header>
```

How do I effectively use CSS Flex to make all the `header > div` elements effectively `float: left;` while making the `header > span` element effectively `float: right;` while keeping it on the same *main axis*?

Comment: Surely you know this is **not** how you ask a question here

Comment: Float and flex are two different things. Can we have a look at your code to be able to answer you ?

Comment: Try position absolute right:0; on that div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header
{
 display: flex;
}

header > div
{
 margin-right: auto;
}

header > span
{
 margin-left: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j5ffw1L7/

Answer (score 5):

With `margin-left:auto` on the "right" span.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: grey;
}
.set {
  height: 75px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1em;
}
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: pink;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="set"></div>
  <div class="set"></div>
  <div class="set"></div>
  <div class="set"></div>
  <div class="set"></div>
  <span class="right">123</span>
</header>
```